# How to distinguish Views from Tables in the EF MetadataWorkspace?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to process the metadata information for an Entity Framework data model by using the *MetadataWorkspace*. I know how to extract all tables, but the following code will return me all views and all tables from the storage model.

```
using ( NorthwindEntities dbContext = new NorthwindEntities() )
{
    MetadataWorkspace workspace = dbContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    string temp = ( dbContext.Categories as ObjectQuery ).ToTraceString();
    IEnumerable<EntityType> tables = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>( DataSpace.SSpace );
}
```

When I take a look at the edmx file, I can see that there is an attribute named *store:Type* that describes which *EntitySet* is a table and which is a View. Such property is not esposed by the EntityType object:

```
<EntitySet Name="Invoices" EntityType="NorthwindModel.Store.Invoices" store:Type="Views">
```

So my question is: Is there a way to recognize which EntitySet is a table and which is a View by using only the MetadataWorkspace (I mean without processing the XML ;))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

After digging deeper in the EF MetadataWorkspace I believe I found a solution:

```
using ( AdventureWorksEntities dbContext = new AdventureWorksEntities() )
{
    MetadataWorkspace mw = dbContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    dbContext.Locations.ToTraceString();
    EntityContainer entityContainer = mw.GetItems<EntityContainer>( DataSpace.SSpace ).Single();
    EntitySet entitySet = entityContainer.GetEntitySetByName( "Location", true );
    string type = entitySet.MetadataProperties[ "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator:Type" ].Value.ToString();
}
```

If I should be honest it is really difficult to work with the Entity Framework metadata. At least they should do strongly-typed properties.